# Why do Sitecore standard values not get propagated?

Tags: sitecore

I have some items in the content tree that are currently just being used as data items. However, I want to add a layout and various sublayouts to them and I don't want to have to do it manually. Currently these items don't have any presentation details set.

So, I've added the presentation details to the standard values of the template that these items are using. I thought that the items would start using these sublayouts straight away. I know that if a default value is put in after the template has started to be used and the item already has a value the standard values will not overwrite this value, but since the items don't currently have any presentation details (and I've tried resetting them) I thought this would work.

It's probably worth noting that the reason I'm doing this is for previewing purposes so although these can be published, it doesn't necessarily have to happen.

Comment: Have you made sure that the template item is pointing to the right standard values item? On the template there is a field for pointing that out. (It should select the subitem called __standard values by default, but it might have bugged)

Comment: +1 as I didn't know that was there. But no, it's pointing to the right __standard values.

Comment: Do you remember what fixed your issue? There's no accepted answer here... Anyway I just had a similar issue, Standard values didn't get propagated. In my case rebuilding index fixed the issue, as my items fetched from an index which probably didn't know yet there were default values. It was certainly not the first place I looked, hopefully this comment may save other people some time...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not know why your solution isn't working but you could see if reseting the fields back to the standard values sorts the problem.

In the content editor select a data item, then from the ribbon select the version tab and click the reset button (make sure standard fields are visible).

Select the layouts field and reset it to standard values.

This will at least indicate if you have values setup on the standard values correctly.

Comment: I've tried that. And it didn't work. As in it didn't reset to what are in the standard values.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reset the Layout on the items (Not the standard values). It could be that you have changed the layouts on the data items, or some other random thing that may have happened, and it needs to be reset.

Comment: You mean on the items in the content tree (under /sitecore/content)? Cos that's where I did hit reset.

Comment: Yeah, that is where I was meaning.